# PHP Concataenate string before and after array

Tags: php, email, string-concatenation, implode

I'm building a web form of sorts that emails the results of the form to a recipient. Everything pretty much works except the client has several checkboxes that are checked on the form, then whichever ones are checked are sent in the email. I am storing them all in an array, and using implode() to insert a `<br>` after each one in the email.

However before each one, the client would like a a bold **X**. I know only 2 parameters can be passed through implode, so is there another way that this can be accomplished? I have below my code that runs implode() and puts  a break after each selected checkbox in the array.

```
if(isset($_POST['assesmentBox']) && is_array($_POST['assesmentBox']) 
&& count($_POST['assesmentBox']) > 0){
   $selectedAssesmentBox = implode("<br>", $_POST['assesmentBox']);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Nothing a little concatenation can't handle:

```
if(isset($_POST['assesmentBox']) && is_array($_POST['assesmentBox']) 
&& count($_POST['assesmentBox']) > 0){

   $selectedAssesmentBox = "<b>X</b>" . implode("<br><b>X</b>", $_POST['assesmentBox']) . "<b>X</b>";
}
```

This just starts the string off with a bold X, appends the `<br>` and a bold X on the next line, closing with a final bold X.